# Catching a gcc/glibc fatal error

Tags: io

I have a binary that occasionally throws a fatal error. I have no access to the source code, but it can be something like the following `C++` code compiled as `test.a`:

```
#include <ctime>
int main() {
   int *a = new int;
   delete a;
   time_t t=time(0);
   if (t%2==0)
      delete a;
   return 0;
}
```

In approximately 50% of runs it leads to the error. What is important, this type of error cannot be caught through the redirecting of `stderr`:

```
$ ./test.a 2>/tmp/Error
*** Error in `./test.a': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000007de010 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I asked, why this happens, I received an answer that "`gcc` (and probably `glibc`) open `/dev/tty` directly to output such fatal errors bypassing IO redirection".

However, it would be very nice to have a way to catch this error from a script. As it occurs randomly and not all the time, it would be useful to retry, e.g.:

```
while :; do
    ./test.a 2>/tmp/Error
    ERROR="$(</tmp/Error)"
    if [ -z "$ERROR" ]; then
        echo "Smooth run!"
        break
    else
        echo "Error occured. Retry!"
    fi
done
```

This of course does not work and in 50% cases outputs this:

```
*** Error in `./test.a': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000df3010 ***
./test.sh: line 10: 16788 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./test.a 2> /tmp/Error
Smooth run!
```

Therefore, I wonder, if there is a way to catch a fatal error and then make a retry to run the bugged binary (I primarily look for a linux solution)?

**EDIT:**

If a binary is called directly from the script, the desired behaviour can be achieved by checking the exit status:

```
while :; do
    ./test.a
    if (( $? == 0 )); then
        echo "Smooth run!"
        break
    else
        echo "Error occured. Retry!"
    fi
done
```

Of course, for this to work the callable executable itself must be written properly. In my real case, for example, the error-causing binary itself is called from another binary. Let us consider `test2.a` as the result of compilation of the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   std::system("./test.a");
   cout<<"Execution of test.a finished"<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

In this case call of `./test2.a` always exits with status `0`, as crash during the `system()` call does not interrupt the execution of the binary:

```
*** Error in `./test.a': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000002431010 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
Execution of test.a finished
Smooth run!
```

How to circumvent this (as I cannot modify the binaries) I still do not know.

Comment: What about `gdb`-ing the core dump, can you see at least a stack trace?

Comment: @peterh But how do I know from within the script that core dump occurred agh the first place?

Comment: I don't understand, please correct around "agh"

Comment: @peterh Sorry. But how do I know from within the script that core dump occurred **in** the first place?